# Mongoose cannot use simple methods from within self

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to use findAndUpdate from within the object class but it's not working.

**Getting the following error**

```
findByIdAndUpdate is not a function
```

The code

**Inside**

```
gameScheme.methods.makeNextRound = function() {
```

**First thing, assign self (Before any lines)**

```
var self = this;
```

**Returning a Promise**

```
return self.findByIdAndUpdate(
                self._id,
                { $push: { "rounds": { storyTitle: story.name } } }
            ).exec();
```

Cannot know how to get self properly from Mongoose since this method is defined before

```
// we need to create a model using it
let Game = mongoose.model('Game', gameScheme);

// make this available to our users in our Node applications
module.exports = Game;
```

On a side note, just using update doesn't work. The rounds do not get concatenated.

Also I think it's very unwise to use game.rouds[0] = "some round" or pushing directly and saving due to nodes async nature. (document miss match)

Comment: I think that you need to use `self.model("Game").findOneAndUpdate`

Comment: Where did you find the documentation for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Mongoose documentation for Schemas](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html) you define `.methods` and `.statics` on the *schema*. However, MongoDB methods are called directly on the *model*.

```
gameScheme.methods.makeNextRound = function () {
  return this.model("Game").findByIdAndUpdate(this._id,
};
```

> [Important](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/model-definition.html): the actual interaction with the data happens with the Model that you obtain through mongoose.model or db.model. That's the object that you can instantiate or that you can call .find(), .findOne(), etc upon. Don't confuse schemas and actual models!